# Translation in Symfony 6

Tags: symfony

Summary : I'm going back to symfony after years not using it (last version was symfony 2). I've then installed the newest maintained version Symfony 6.3.

I'm currently trying to handle one of the most basics problem is nowadays framework : translations.

But whatever I'm doing it doesn't seems to work (meaning i don't see the translation in frontend).

Here are the files that could interest you

`config/packages/translation.yaml`

```
framework:
    default_locale: en
    translator:
        default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%\translations'
        fallbacks:
            - en
```

`translations/messages.fr.php`

```
<?php

return [
    'Symfony is great' => "J'aime Symfony",
];
```

That part seems file cause if I extract the translation fr; the translations appears in the export log. So my issue is really on the how to make this translation effective.

Here is my homepage (that i'm using only as a language chooser and to test the language switching process)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Language Selector</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flag.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="language-selector-top">
            <h1>Configuration</h1>
            Current Locale is : {{ app.request.locale }}
            Try to translate following {{ "Symfony is great"|trans }}
        </div>
        <div class="language-selector">
            <div class="language-flag" data-lang="en_US">
                <img src="images/usa.jpg" alt="USA Flag">
                <div class="language-text">Configure my account in English !</div>
            </div>
            <div class="language-flag" data-lang="fr_FR">
                <img src="images/french.png" alt="French Flag">
                <div class="language-text">Configurer mon compte en Français !</div>
            </div>
            <div class="language-flag" data-lang="es_ES">
                <img src="images/mexican.png" alt="Mexican Flag">
                <div class="language-text">Configurar mi cuenta en Mexicano !</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/flag.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Clicking to a flag will trigger an ajax that is supposed to change the language

```
    #[Route('/language/update')]
    public function updateLanguage(Request $request):JsonResponse
    {
        $previousLocale = $request->getLocale();
        $language = $request->get('language');


        // Update the Symfony locale based on the selected language
        //$this->localeSwitcher->setLocale($language);
        $request->setLocale($language);

        return new JsonResponse(
            [
                'oldLocale' => $previousLocale,
                'newLocale' => $language
            ]
        );
    }
```

As a result the ajax return me the following console log

> {"oldLocale":"en","newLocale":"fr_FR"}

The issue is that when the page is reloading the language seems to keep being "en" as nothing is translated at all.

```
     flag.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const selectedLanguage = flag.getAttribute('data-lang');

        // Send an AJAX request to update the Symfony locale
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/language/update', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    // Reload the page after successful language update
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    window.location.href = '/';
                } else {
                    console.error('Failed to update language.');
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.send('language=' + encodeURIComponent(selectedLanguage));
    });
```

Thanks for your assistance in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imo, you have to store the `selected locale` in the session then use a listener (`kernel.event_listener`) to set the locale from the session for each request

notice that: symfony itself has the `LocaleListener` (priority 16 iirc), so your listener has to have higher priority.

Example:

```
#[Route('/language/update')]
public function updateLanguage(Request $request):JsonResponse
{
    $previousLocale = $request->getLocale();
    $language = $request->get('language'); // should rename the param to locale
     
    $request->setLocale($language);

    $request->getSession()->set('locale', $language);

    return new JsonResponse([
        'oldLocale' => $previousLocale,
        'newLocale' => $language
    ]);
}
```

```
namespace App\Listener;

class LocaleListener
{
    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event): void
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        // en_US: fallback to the default locale if it's not existed
        $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('locale', 'en_US'));
    }
}
```

in services.yaml

```
App\Listener\LocaleListener:
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest, priority: 17 }
```

**In case you don't want to handle the locale stuff by yourself, there's a bundle for it** https://github.com/lunetics-org/LocaleBundle

Comment: Note: you can find the current priority of the localelistener with `php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher kernel.request | grep Locale`

Comment: Will you be kind enough to show me how you will do that ? I don't understand why the documentation is not mentionning that...

Comment: @pjng sorry to bother you again, using your solution leads me to the following error : TypeError:
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::setLocale(): Argument #1 ($locale) must be of type string, null given, called in C:\Users\chris\Desktop\projets\my_project_directory\src\Listener\LocaleListener.php on line 13

NB from your code i had to add the use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;

Comment: Ok i figure it out, i had to use         if($request->getSession()->get('locale') == null){
            $request->getSession()->set('locale','en');
        }
Because on the first loading the locale is not defined, but after that, the translation is working as expected. Thank you very much !

Comment: better solution: `$request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('locale', 'en));`